# convert json with square brackets to php array

Tags: php, datatables

I am trying to discover what php array gets you this json

```
{
  "sEcho": 67,
  "iTotalRecords": "4075",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "4075",
  "aaData": [
    [
      "215",
      "Manaus",
      "BRA",
      "Amazonas",
      "1255049"
    ],
    [
      "216",
      "BelÃ©m",
      "BRA",
      "ParÃ¡",
      "1186926"
    ],
    [
      "217",
      "Guarulhos",
      "BRA",
      "SÃ£o Paulo",
      "1095874"
    ],
    [
      "218",
      "GoiÃ¢nia",
      "BRA",
      "GoiÃ¡s",
      "1056330"
    ],
    [
      "219",
      "Campinas",
      "BRA",
      "SÃ£o Paulo",
      "950043"
    ],
    [
      "220",
      "SÃ£o GonÃ§alo",
      "BRA",
      "Rio de Janeiro",
      "869254"
    ],
    [
      "221",
      "Nova IguaÃ§u",
      "BRA",
      "Rio de Janeiro",
      "862225"
    ],
    [
      "222",
      "SÃ£o LuÃ­s",
      "BRA",
      "MaranhÃ£o",
      "837588"
    ],
    [
      "223",
      "MaceiÃ³",
      "BRA",
      "Alagoas",
      "786288"
    ],
    [
      "224",
      "Duque de Caxias",
      "BRA",
      "Rio de Janeiro",
      "746758"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am trying this

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "more foo",
    "st" => "bar",
    "ty" => "stuff",
    "multi" => array(
             "array" => "foo",
             "the" => "stuff"
         ),
         array(array(
             "array" => "foo",
             "the" => "stuff"
         )),
         array(array(
             "array" => "foo",
             "the" => "stuff"
         )),
         array(array(
             "array" => "foo",
             "the" => "stuff"
         ))
    );
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($array));
echo "</pre>";
```

but my json has a curly bracket

> {"foo":"more
>   foo","st":"bar","ty":"stuff","multi":{"array":"foo","the":"stuff"},"0":[{"array":"foo","the":"stuff"}],"1":[{"array":"foo","the":"stuff"}],"2":[{"array":"foo","the":"stuff"}]}

How can i correct my array to produce the json?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many arrays of depth, and you shouldn't specify the key. In PHP arrays if you set a string key and JSON encode it, it will produce an object not an array.

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "more foo",
    "st" => "bar",
    "ty" => "stuff",
    "multi" => array(
        array(
            '215',
            'Manaus',
            'BRA'
        ),
        array(
            '216',
            'BelÃ©m',
            'BRA'
        ),
        array(
            '217',
            'Guarulhos',
            'BRA'
        )
    )
);

echo json_encode($array);
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "foo": "more foo",
    "st": "bar",
    "ty": "stuff",
    "multi": [
        [
            "215",
            "Manaus",
            "BRA"
        ],
        [
            "216",
            "BelÃ©m",
            "BRA"
        ],
        [
            "217",
            "Guarulhos",
            "BRA"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use numeric indices! Anything with a string as a key must produce curly braces, because thats the only way to have these keys in javascript.

```
json_encode(array("hello", "world")

["hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 1):

json array indexes MUST be numerical.
Any non numerical index will be converted into a json object.
That's why it is rendered into curly brackets .

About your initial question, the following PHP code :
    header("Content-type: application/json");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type"); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false"); 
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 60");

```
include "./inc/funclib.inc.php";
$array = array (
    "sEcho" =>  67,
    "iTotalRecords" => "4075",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => "4075",
    "aaData" => array (
        array ( "215", "Manaus", "BRA", "Amazonas", "1255049"),
        array ( "216", "Belem",  "BRA", "Para¡", "1186926"),
        array ( "217", "Guarulhos", "BRA", "Sao Paulo", "1095874")
    ));

echo jsonIndent(json_encode($array));
```

returns that output:

```
{
  "sEcho":67,
  "iTotalRecords":"4075",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords":"4075",
  "aaData":[
    [
      "215",
      "Manaus",
      "BRA",
      "Amazonas",
      "1255049"
    ],
    [
      "216",
      "Belem",
      "BRA",
      "Para\u00a1",
      "1186926"
    ],
    [
      "217",
      "Guarulhos",
      "BRA",
      "Sao Paulo",
      "1095874"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Which looks like what you are looking for.
I hope this will help :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have curly brackets because you specified both keys and values, you will need to specify just values.

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "more foo",
    "st" => "bar",
    "ty" => "stuff",
    "multi" => array(
              "foo",
             "stuff"
         ),
         array(array(
              "foo",
             "stuff"
         )),
         array(array(
             "foo",
             "stuff"
         )),
         array(array(
              "foo",
             "stuff"
         ))
    );
```